# Update multiple selector of same components if there is change in one

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components

Child component date filter component(selector - 'app-date-filter') where i select date. I am using the same filter component three times in my dashboard page. I am passing data to date-filter component from dashboard with attribute binding.Now if i update one date it should update at all three places in my dashboard page. Any suggestion how can i achieve this?

Comment: You can use two way data binding in app-date-filter like <app-date-filter [(date)]="dateFilter"></app-date-filter>

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal-Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the same object for binding the date in your all 'app-date-filter'. Make sure this object is part of your dashboard component.